# Unproven vs. Unsubstantiated

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Watching Meet the Press today I watched Chuck Todd insist that an accusation was unproven, but not unsubstantiated.  What is the difference between these terms?

"You have firsthand accounts. They're unproven but they are not unsubstantiated. You have a, you have a first-hand account. We have somebody that disagrees with that first-hand account. But they are substantiated, no?" - Chuck Todd

http://www.nbcnews.com/meet-the-press/meet-press-october-16-2016-n667251

Comment: *Unproven* means it could be false. *Substantiated* means it cannot be dismissed as unworthy of consideration.

Comment: In this example I believe the speaker is using *unsubstantiated* as a lesser value than *proof* i.e. the evidence was not totally without substance, but perhaps not strong enough to constitute *proof*. Whether *substantiate* and *prove* are equal, or whether the former is less conclusive than the latter, is perhaps debateable.

Comment: Not unsubstantiated means that the story seems to hang together. The information available suggests that the allegations are true. This is quite different from the allegations being proven in a court of law.

Comment: @RichardKayser I would agree that that is how *substantiate* is being used here. But *substantiate* seems to have a broad range of interpretation. OED sense 4, indicates it both as *proof* and (in the same definition) merely *to give good grounds for*. The latter seems to me to be rather less than *proof*.  - *4. trans. To prove the truth of (a charge, claim, etc.); to demonstrate or verify (something) by evidence; to give good grounds for, to justify.* (This is a very interesting question).

Comment: An argument or assertion that is without substance has no factual support whatsoever; an argument or assertion that is not proved may be strong but still fall short of being established as factual by a preponderance of the evidence or beyond a reasonable doubt. It's easy to see why "not unsubstantiated" is an easier hurdle to clear than "not unproved."

Comment: @SvenYargs Yet, according to the OED it *can* mean "to prove the truth of".

Comment: @SvenYargs I don't think it's easy to see at all.  I would bet the vast majority of people could not definitively make the distinction.  Even searching online it's easy to find one definition including the other.  Perhaps it was simply imprecise usage by Chuck Todd, and should have been phrased differently?

Comment: @RichardKayser Somewhat analogous to the different levels of proof in criminal and civil cases perhaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your quotation, the speaker is using 'prove' in the sense of 'definite conclusion from facts' and 'substantiate' in the sense of 'support with evidence', where evidence does not amount to a totally rigorous proof but only provides some degree of reason for us to believe something.

'Substantiated' can also be properly used to mean 'proven', which was likely the cause of confusion between Todd and Pence during the interview.

Comment: Not necessarily as true, but worthy of further investigation.

Answer (score 1):

Uncorroborated would likely be the best word with which both Todd and Pence could agree.

> Todd was dancing on the head of a pin because the charges were detailed though uncorroborated, Pence feeling that the charges were lacking support, hence unsubstantiated (e.g., no witnesses, no smoking gun).

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! We strive to provide objective and well-researched answers. This answer seems good, however, if you expand and provide further evidence, this could become a great answer! Take the [Tour] and see [answer] for more.

Answer (score 0):

I like ol' Chuck, but I think he is wrong on this one.  Mirriam-Webster defines "substantiate" as "to prove the truth of" or "to establish by proof or competent evidence".  Granted, this is a layman's definition and not necessarily a legal definition.  So I dug deeper.  Based on my quick Googling, it seems that when someone makes a claim of wrong-doing or abuse, typically an investigation is done.  If credible evidence is found to help support the claim, then the claim is deemed to be substantiated--not yet proven, but worthy of further investigation.  The victim's testimony alone does not constitute substantiation.